# iOS: How to make UIWebView 50% transparent?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview

I want to make a UIWebView whose background is 50% transparent, but whose content e.g.  are not transparent at all.

Is such a thing possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
webView.alpha=0.5f;

[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[webView setOpaque:NO];
```

Comment: I think this only gets you halfway there. You still have to make the body of the web page semi-transparent.

Comment: for instant help http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is possible, maybe. See this blog post:

http://erikloehfelm.blogspot.com/2009/04/transparent-background-on-iphone.html

Making the background semi-transparent depends on whether or not you can set the CSS color of the web page's BODY element to a semi-transparent color (instead of "transparent").

Also, this blog post doesn't show how to do this if you don't control the HTML of the web page you're trying to display, but it's possible with the `UIWebView` to programmatically change this color once the page contents have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with changing **transparent** to **whatever color / alpha** for the `webView.backgroundColor` and the html `<body>` css style to find a combination that you like best.  Example with `loadHTMLString`:

```
- (void)embedYouTubeWithVideoID:(NSString *)videoID {
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CGFloat w = webView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat h = webView.frame.size.height;
    NSString *ytUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&fs=1&hd=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showsearch=0", videoID];
    NSString *embed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                       <html>\
                           <head>\
                               <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = %0.0f\"/>\
                           </head>\
                           <body style=\"background:transparent; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px\">\
                               <div>\
                                   <object width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\">\
                                       <param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\" />\
                                       <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\" />\
                                       <param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\" />\
                                       <param name=\"quality\" value=\"high\" />\
                                       <embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" />\
                                   </object>\
                               </div>\
                           </body>\
                       </html>", w, w, h, ytUrlString, ytUrlString, w, h];
    [webView loadHTMLString:embed baseURL:nil];
}
```